# Access files of Android device without the login code

Tags: adb, backup, data-recovery

Long story short. The father of a friend of mine died and he asked me if I could have a look at the father's phone to see if there might be any images or other stuff he might find relevant. The problem however, is that it is locked and no-one in his family knows the code.

I thought of a few ways to tackle this, but most of them require USB debugging to be enabled (which it is not), so stuff like ADB or so is impossible (or is it?).

Then I thought of the program Autopsy, which we used in school to scan an entire device. However, back then, the image of the device was handed to us. I understand I could use the program dd to copy an raw image, however, is it possible to do so on a locked Android device which is not rooted?

Any other suggestions to how I can solve this? Thanks!

Comment: The simple answer: No. The long answer: Your friend has to contact Google and as the heir claim to get access to the used Google account (hopefully the gmail address is known). Via Google account you can then try to unlock the device via find-my-device functionality.

Comment: I'll have to contact him if he has the gmail, thanks for the suggestion